# Display posts with one of the tags of my current post

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I have a few posts on my WP site, and each post can have 1-n tags.

For the last few hours now I am trying to display the newest 3 posts with one of the tags of my current post.

Sample:

Post A has tags "Apple", "Banana", "Orange"

Post B has tags "Banana", "Grapefruit"

Post C has tags "Apple", "Grapefruit"

---

If I am on Post A, I want to display Post B and C as my related posts (as B has tag "Banana" and post C has tag "Apple").

If I am on Post B, I want to display Post C as my related post (as C has tag "Grapefruit")

What I have tried so far:

```
function twr_related_posts__tag() { 

    $content = '<h3 class="mt-5">Related Posts</h3> ';

    $myTopics_id = "";
    $myTopics_array = [];

    /* Get all Tag IDs of current post */
    $myTopics = get_the_tags();

    if ($myTopics) {
        foreach($myTopics as $tag) {                             
            $myTopics_array[] = $tag->term_id;
        }
    }
    
    
    $args = array(  
        'tag__in'        => $myTopics_array,
        'tag__not_in'    => array( 16, 17, 18 ), 
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1 
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    

    while ( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query -> the_post();
      
        $content .= '<p>'. get_the_title() .'</p>';

    endwhile; 
    


    wp_reset_query();

    return $content;

}

add_shortcode('related_posts__tag','twr_related_posts__tag');
```

I am getting the ids of the post tags, putting them into an array.
Put the array in a 'tag__in' clause for a WP_Query.
Display the titles of the result set.

But the result set is wrong.
First, it displays the current post as a related post (what should not be the case, the current post should be excluded). And the other results are just wrong.

What do I need to change?

Comment: One problem immediately apparent, is that you are _imploding_ those IDs into a comma-separated string, that you then wrap into an array. So this is an array containing one single element now. That is something completely different, than an array of individual ID values.

Comment: oh man... you're right! It just "looks" like an array, but of course it's a string now.. give me a second, I will try to fix it and see, what's the outcome now

Comment: hm, I have removed the implode method and changed the query line to   'tag__in'  => $myTopics_array. Now I am getting similar results on Post A and B.  Post A displays Post B, but Post B does not display Post A but Post B itself.

Comment: Sure there is no overlap with the tag IDs you are explicitly excluding via `tag__not_in`?

Comment: right again, there IS an overlap. So I need to filter the tags anyhow before I am going to fill the array

Comment: _“the current post should be excluded”_ - that part’s probably easiest, if you add `post__not_in` to your criteria. Add `global $post;` at the start of your function, so that the global post object is available, and then `'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )`

Comment: You can use [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to filter out the IDs that are in $myTopics_array. `$tagsNotIn = array_diff( [16, 17, 18], $myTopics_array);` should leave only those of those three IDs listed there, that are not contained in `$myTopics_array`. (Don’t get confused by the `[…]` part, that’s just a shorter way of writing `array(…)`)

Comment: Ah, I see what you're trying to achieve. But the problem is, that Post A has one of the tag ids that should be ignored/excluded, but also another tag that I want to be able to filter on. So I still guess I need to fill the query array with only the "allowed" ids.

Comment: Yes, filtering with only allowed IDs probably makes more sense then. But you should be able to use this exactly the other way around then – `$tagsIn = array_diff( $myTopics_array, [16, 17, 18] );` would leave only those IDs from `$myTopics_array`, that are not contained in the second array `[16, 17, 18]`.

Comment: This is working exactly as what I had hoped for! Thank you so much @CBroe - after all these hours of searching ......... but as I only know a tiny bit of PHP magic and combined with WP ... I was really lost. Now, if you would like to add your answer I am more than happy to mark it as the accepted one!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'tag__in'        => array( $myTopics_id ),
```

With that, you did not actually supply an array of post IDs, but an array with one single element, since `$myTopics_id` is a string value of comma-separated IDs.

As for not getting all the posts you wanted, that turned out to be an overlap between the tag IDs specified for `tag__in` and `tag__not_in`. Since you got a fixed lists of tag IDs you don’t want here, it makes sense to only filter via `tag__in`, and remove the unwanted IDs from the array that contains the tags of the current post, `array_diff` can help with that:

```
$tagsIn = array_diff( $myTopics_array, [16, 17, 18] );
```

And to exclude the current post itself, you can just add a `post__not_in` filter. Putting `global $post;` at the start of your function imports the global post object into the function scope, after that you can use `$post->ID` to get the ID of the currently viewed post.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete code to the problem if anyone is ever searching for a similar solution. Thanks to @CBroe once again, super helpful!

```
function twr_related_posts__tag() { 
    
    global $post;

    $content = '<h3 class="mt-5">Related Posts</h3> ';

    $myTopics_id = "";
    $myTopics_array = [];

    /* Get all Tag IDs of current post */
    $myTopics = get_the_tags();

    if ($myTopics) {
        foreach($myTopics as $tag) {
            $myTopics_array[] = $tag->term_id;
        }
    }
    
    
    $args = array(  
        'tag__in'        => array_diff( $myTopics_array, [16, 17, 18] ),  // use array, but exclude specific tag ids
        'post__not_in'   => array( $post->ID ),
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 3 
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    

    while ( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query -> the_post();
      
        $content .= '<p>'. get_the_title() .'</p>';

    endwhile; 
    


    wp_reset_query();

    return $content;

}

add_shortcode('related_posts__tag','twr_related_posts__tag');
```